# how to add data into list view from datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listview

I have one confusion with SQL Query.

I have three tables, student, books, book_taken_by_student.
In the last table we have all the details about books taken by students.

In list view I bind the student name as row vies and different books name as column vies from student and books table.
The list view look like

### | Book1 | Book2 | Book 3 | Book 4|

### A  |

### B  |

### C  |

### D  |

### E  |

F  |

---

Now with help of book_taken_by_student table I want to bind Yes or No in front of student name  related with book name taken by them

How I can solve this question.

Finally I want to show my list view like this

### | Book1 | Book2 | Book 3 | Book 4|

### A  |   Yes      | No        |  Yes       |  Yes

### B  | No        |  Yes       |  Yes     | No

### C  |  No        |  Yes       |  Yes     | No

### D  |   Yes | No        |  Yes       |  Yes

### E  |   Yes | No        |  Yes       |  Yes

F  |  No        |  Yes       |  Yes   | Yes

---

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You are probably facing the problem the wrong way (trying to use row values as column names), but give a try to the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function. Sorry I'm no SQL Server expert I can't help you.